# Windows 11 styled DataGrid

Tags: c#, winui-3

I'm trying to make a file manager for Windows using the Winappsdk and WinUI 3. But I've run into a dead end: I need a easy to use table, or a multi columned list.

- Turns out you can make a multi column list, but you won't be able to let the user resize the columns without a lot of extra coding, right?
- After realizing this, I looked to see if I could find a table control, but WinUI 3 doesn't natively have one. So I looked at the Windows Community Datagrid, which was looking very promising except it has Windows 10 styling. Is there a table control somewhere that looks like Windows 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, there is no way to make the DataGrid looks like Windows 11 styling. And I suggest you could post the thread to the [github issue](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues) for the future request.

If you just want to modify the styles and templates for the DataGrid control, you can modify the default `ControlTemplate` to give the control a unique appearance. Refer to the Doc:[How to - Customize the DataGrid control through UI formatting options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/styling_formatting_options)